# Parse URI from string.xml

Tags: android, string, uri

I appear to have got stuck when trying to parse a URI in my Android app

I have got a reference to a button that has been clicked, and I want to use this reference to parse a specific string from the strings.xml

```
currentView = view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
String[] splitId = currentView.split("/");
String clickedButton = splitId[1];

Uri currentLink = Uri.parse();
```

So here, clicked button gives me instagramLink or similar, where I now want to use this to get the string

```
<string name="instagramLink">https://www.instagram.com/xxxxxxx/</string>
```

I seem to be struggling to find a way to do this, so any help would be appreciated. I've attempted to google, but I don't seem to have found anything I understand to help me.

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem? do you want to convert your string to uri ?

Comment: Uri currentLink = Uri.parse(clickedButton);

Comment: I want to use the string as the URI, but I can't seem to get it in a format where it picks up the link, putting clickedButton in just gives me currentLink as instagramLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, hopefully this will help someone else too!

So to get a string from the strings xml, and put it into the URL is as simple as this...

```
view.getId()
```

And then here I have a switch/ case statement, where if the view.getId is x then do y etc

```
Uri currentLink = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.instagramLink));
```

Where I am still using

```
<string name="instagramLink">https://www.instagram.com/xxxxxxx/</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the string you defined in strings.xml as the following :

```
String nav_facebook_link = getResources().getString(R.string.nav_facebook_link);
```

Then you can give it to Uri.parse() method :

```
Uri.parse(nav_facebook_link);
```